# Convert NSString to fetch synthesized information

Tags: iphone, objective-c, nsstring

```
//COPY THIS CODE IN A FRESH PROJECT!!!

//THIS 2 LINES ARE JUST EXAMPLES, OF VALUES PUSHES OUT A DATABASE
NSString *messagelevel1 = @"45";
NSString *currentlevel = @"1";

NSString *HuidigLevel = currentlevel;
NSDecimalNumber *huidigleveldec = [[NSDecimalNumber alloc] initWithString: HuidigLevel];
float HuidigLevelRek = [huidigleveldec floatValue]; 

//HERE IS THE PROBLEM
NSString* LevelTotaal=[[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"messagelevel%.f",HuidigLevelRek];
NSString*result = LevelTotaal;
NSLog(@"%@",result);
// THE ABOVE RESULT SHOULD RETURN THE SAME VALUE AS THE NEXT (messagelevel1) LINE BUT IT RETURNS ONLY "messagelevel1" AND NOT THE VALUE!
NSLog(@"%@",messagelevel1);
```

I want the *result string behaves like the *huidiglevel string and fetch some information, but because the LevelTotaal is a NSString, It doesn't fetch this information. I really got no idea where to google for this problem, searching the Developer docs didn't helped either . Maybe you guys can help me out?

Actually the second NSLog returns the value and to first NSLog just returns messagelevel1. To tell you in short ;)

I hope you guys get what I'm saying!

Comment: This is still not very clear. Can you output the NSLog messages for more clarity on what is actually happening. Also what do you mean by "doesn't fetch this information"?

Comment: Well messagelevel1 returns just 45, result should do the same thing, but because LevelTotaal is an NSString it doesn't think that it had to behave like messagelevel1, it just behave like an static text.

Comment: You get what I'm saying?

Comment: Can you try to give add an NSLog after the third line where you initialize the float value (directly log the float). Maybe it doesn't initialize the float correctly. And you say only the bottom log works, what does the one above logs?

Comment: Well the result one returns static text: messagelevel1 and the messaglevel1 returns 45! So The messagelevel1 should do the same! I changed the code! Copy it in a fresh project! You will see immediately what the problem is!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think what you're trying to do is use variable variables, a system that does not exist in Objective-C. In PHP, you *can* use [variable variables](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.variables.variable.php):

```
$hello = 'abcdef';
$varName = 'hello';

print $$varName; // prints the value of $hello, which is 'abcdef'
```

Like many things in PHP, this is not really a good way to design software. Instead, consider using something like a [`NSDictionary`](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSDictionary_Class/Reference/Reference.html), this allows you to give specific data a *key*.

```
NSMutableDictionary *aDict = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];

[aDict setObject:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:4.5] forKey:@"messageLevel1"];

NSString *result = [aDict objectForKey:@"messageLevel1"];
```

You can obtain the data dynamically, the key can be generated or obtained at runtime.

#### Edit:

Rather than having variables called `messageLevel1`, `messageLevel2`, `messageLevel3` ... `messageLeveln`, just use an array.

```
NSMutableArray *messageLevels = [NSMutableArray array];

[messageLevels addObject:@"1"];
[messageLevels addObject:@"45"];
[messageLevels addObject:@"123"];

NSString *result = [messageLevels objectAtIndex:HuidigLevelRek];
```

Comment: It's all about get the level out the database which can be 1, 2 ,3 ,4 ... and then combine it like messagelevel1, messagelevel2, messagelevel3 and aftherwards it gets a value in a database like this: NSString *messagelevel1 = @"45"; It must be possible! Your answer is not want I want actually, it doesn't need a key. Thanx anyway!

Comment: @Max: Most variable names are not stored anywhere in the compiled executable, so there would be no possible way to reference them by name.

Comment: Just copy the code like I said in a fresh document you will see the problem! this mutablearray is also not what I want, sorry! Just copy and watch the console! I want to see 2 times 45 but I only see it one time! Edit it there to see if something works out!

Comment: @Max: I **know** what you want to see. You **should not** write code this way. You need to properly structure your data so that you can reference it sanely. Like I said, most variable names **are not stored in the compiled executable**.

Comment: Yeah I understand but NSString *messagelevel1 = @"45";
NSString *messagelevel = @"1"; Have almost the same name, but are totally different, I combine these 2 to messagelevel+1 to than fetch the messagelevel1 data (45) from a sql database. So puttin them together in an array is not what I want, is there another option?

Comment: And the values are pushed from a previous viewcontroller so the other levels are not avaible to put in an array!

Comment: @Max: You need to consider a different design, why do you have `messageLevel1`, `messageLevel2`, `messageLevel3` etc, why are they not in array? Sequentially named variables like this is a big code smell. Another code smell is variable variables. See [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_smell) for a definition of code smell.